# How to add new attribute using script?

Tags: magento-1.5

I tried below code -

```
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->addAttribute("eav_attribute", "cv1_price", array("type"=>"decimal"));
    $installer->addAttribute("eav_attribute", "cv1_shipping_cost", array("type"=>"decimal"));
    $installer->endSetup();
```

But I want to add new attribute to all related table.

Comment: for which entity you want attribute?

Comment: @BornCoder - For product

Comment: i gave answer, check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'page_layout', array(
  'type'              => 'varchar',
  'backend'           => '',
  'frontend'          => '',
  'label'             => 'Page Layout',
  'input'             => 'select',
  'class'             => '',
  'source'            => 'catalog/product_attribute_source_layout',
  'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
  'visible'           => true,
  'required'          => false,
  'user_defined'      => false,
  'default'           => '',
  'searchable'        => false,
  'filterable'        => false,
  'comparable'        => false,
  'visible_on_front'  => false,
  'unique'            => false,
  'group'             => 'Design'
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: I want to add new attribute in eav_attribute and catalog_eav_attribute table